# Strange git behavior. commit or stash your changes before switching branches

Tags: git

The following is my problem

It is possible to checkout branches. I can switch from A to B normally.
If I do a `git status` it says nothing to commit same state as origin. 
But there is one branch (lets call it C), where i cant gat on it. If I do a `git checkout C` I get the answer: please first stash or commit file "fileA".

I have to say, that i did a `git update-index --assume-unchanged "filaA"` And "filaA" is on .gitignore

`git stash` : No local cahnges 
`git stash pop` : No entries found

`git checkout <Path to fileA>` solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For stashing the files:

You have to follow this command:

```
git stash
```

and if you want to move the files from stashed to unstaged

```
git stash pop
```

If you want to undo changes what you have done, you can do this:

```
git checkout <Path to fileA>
```

As you mentioned, `fileA` is in `.gitignore`, make sure you have the correct path mentioned in the `.gitignore`.

Let me know if it helps.